# calculus 2 limit question

Tags: limits

Prove that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x = e^a$$ for $a$ not equal to $0$.

Comment: @Aniket Just a note: a descriptive title is at least as important as nice formatting. If you are editing anyway... take a look at the title.

Comment: homework. what have you tried ?

Comment: @NormalHuman I don't know what kind of title you give to a question that apart from being a duplicate, seems to ask questions without showing any effort to proceed with the problem. Actually I should'nt have started to edit this at all.

Comment: @Aniket That works too. That's why I said "If you are editing..."

Comment: @Aniket Hey look, this user has another post like that... just don't bother editing...

Comment: @NormalHuman Yeah I saw it. Its almost like this one, without format, no effort, lifted from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the case of $a > 0$.

Start from one of the definitions of $e$ (probably the only one you started with in your class:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = e
$$
Now consider a sequence $S_n$ each of whose $n$-th term is  $$ \left( left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right) ^a = left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{na}
$$
It is easy to show (using the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition of limits), 
that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = e^a$$
For choose some $\epsilon > 0$.  Then (taking the test $\varepsilon$ in the limit definition to be $\epsilon^{1/a}$, since 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( (S_n)^{1/a} = e $, there exists some finite $\delta$
such that $$n>\delta \rightarrow |(S_n)^{1/a} - e| < \varepsilon = \epsilon^{1/a} $$
so whenever $n>\delta$, 
$$ |S_n - e^a| < \epsilon $$

SO we have establisshed that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(  1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{na} = e^a
$$ Now let $x = na$; when $n$ goes to infinity, so does $x$.  Now $n = a/x$ so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(  1 + \frac{a}{x} \right)^{x} = e^a
$$

The $a < 0$ case goes along similar lines.

Since each term